# haystack solr search ALL fields

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have a solr search engine set up with multiple fields and I want to be able to search ALL fields.

I can do a `.filter(content='string')` but this only searches whatever fields are in the `document=True`

**EDIT**
Also, some of the non `document=True` fields have different filters/tokenisers applied so im guessing that would not work with adding them into a single field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@neolaser: I think what you want can be achieved by using DisMax search. It allows searching through multiple fields and specify the boost value for each of them. For more details:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had already given the correct answer as it was the "closest" one given after a while, but I did end up using dismax! So thanks for the answer, im sure this will eb useful for somebody else too!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can make a second field with 'use_template' and a template displaying ALL fields.

I never tried to do this, but this sound a good way to do it to me.

**EDIT since OP comment:**

Then my best bet is to eaither sublass SearchQueryset to add a method or to create a function that will loop and all fields in your SearchIndex and do something like:

```
qs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)
for field in fieldlist:
   qs = qs.filter_or(**{'field':query})
```

I have no idea if this works at all but that's worth trying.

Comment: I have updated the question. I had been doing what you suggested but I need the fields to have different filters/tokenisers applied :( Thanks for the answer, in most cases this would work

Comment: Thanks for the update. the solution was to subclass a series of haystack related classes giving me more control over how solr works. Although I think that means that I wont be able to use another backend...luckily solr is great. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can search all the fields buy including them all into your [filtering query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) parameter or by naming them in the query string (e.g. if you need to search for "keyword" search for "((field_1:keyword) OR (field_2:keyword) OR (field_3: keyword))" instead).

However, it is usually better to have a dedicated field concatenating all the others you need to search and search this single field. You can set up a [copyfield](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_do_I_use_copyField_with_wildcards.3F) in your schema to have that content generated automatically when your document is indexed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question saying that some fields have different filters/tokenisers applied which I think may rule out our second option. How would I use the first option in haystack?

Comment: If you use different tokenisers you need to name your fields explicitly in the query. Is that a problem? I can imagine situation when you need to search an unpredictable number of dynamic fields, but generally if your fields set is static, just build a proper query like in example above. Don't afraid of it being long, Solr is okay with that.